# Running sh file only works if cd'd to scripts directory

Tags: shell, filenames

I'm trying to run a `.sh` file, through the `./file.sh` syntax. I, wrongly, thought it'd be possible to run:

```
./usr/bin/foo/bar.sh
```

which just yields `"No such file or directory"`. However, if I run:

```
cd /usr/bin/foo && ./bar.sh
```

It works perfectly. Why isn't the first approach possible?

*(I'm using Lubuntu 14)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The . at the beginning of a directory path means that it is a relative path starting at the current working directory. Without the . it starts at the file system root.

So you would have to run `/usr/bin/foo/bar.sh` without a preceding dot.
The dot is only needed when you are located in the same directory as the file to distinguish it from an eventually existing file with the same name in /bin which can be run from everywhere without adding a directory.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I found yours to be best explaining. I thought the `.` stood for something like "run the following script". Obviously very wrong hehe.

Answer (score 2):

Dots matter.

Instead of:

```
./usr/bin/foo/bar.sh
```

Use:

```
/usr/bin/foo/bar.sh
```

#### Discussion

Consider:

```
./usr/bin/foo/bar.sh
```

This starts in the *current* directory, `./`, and looks for the subdirectory `usr`.  If the current directory contains no such subdirectory, you will see the message:

```
bash: ./usr/bin/foo/bar.sh: No such file or directory
```

By contrast, consider:

```
cd /usr/bin/foo && ./bar.sh
```

This ignores the current directory entirely and cd's to `/usr/bin/foo`.

Answer (score 0):

`.` means current directory. Just run it like this:

```
/usr/bin/foo/bar.sh
```

When you place a `.` before it looks for:

```
whateverdirectory/yourein/usr/bin/foo/bar.sh
```